# Перемещение приложения из платформы .NET Framework 4 на .NET Framework 2

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Я пишу приложение на C# в Visual Studio 2010.

Почему-то когда только создавал проект не обратил внимание на использующуюся платформу, по умолчанию стояла .NET Framework 4. Сейчас же, когда 60% программы написана, у меня появилась возможность (вру, банальная забывчивость) проверить ее работоспособность на Windows XP, у самого стояла Windows 7. У Windows XP установлена была .NET Framework 2, приложение не запустилось, а выдало ошибку что нужно установить 4-й Framework.

Я попробовал в Visual Studio изменить платформу через свойства проекта. Вроде бы получилось, конечно же пришлось не много подкорректировать программу, точнее пришлось удалить namespace Linq со всех файлов и несколько ссылок. Ошибок никаких Visual Studio не выдавала, поэтому попробовал скомпилировать... не получилось. Компиляция прошла успешно, но еще приложение не запустилось как оно уже закрылось и Windows искал ошибку, но так ничего не нашел.

Вопрос: в чем может быть проблема ошибки программы? Или может нужно по другому как-то поменять платформу?

Подскажите пожалуйста, просто не хочется весь проект переписывать заново, и кто знает, может он все равно не будет работать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET Framework v4 поддерживается на Windows XP SP3, поэтому лучше продолжать писать под него и требовать наличия необходимой версии при установке.

Возможно, цепляются неподходящие сборки. Про [совместимость версий в .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ff602939.aspx).

Если приложение писалось на основе Windows Forms, то особых проблем для отката быть не должно, в качестве эксперимента можно создать новый проект Form под .NET 2 и перекинуть в него по одиночке файлы из готового проекта.

Comment: За совет спасибо. Наверное так и сделаю, буду продолжать писать на .NET Framework 4. Приложение пишу на WinForms и я пробовал перекидывать файлы в новый проект .NET Framework 2, к сожалению не помогает, ошибка та же.

Answer (score 0):

В принципе я все таки попробовал перенести приложение на платформу .NET Framework 2. Когда поменял платформу в свойствах проекта, запустил его не через CTRL+F5 а просто F5 - запуск с отладкой.

Сразу же выявилось несколько несоответствий с версией Framework. Поменял кое что, где-то подкорректировал, и все работает:)